# Linq query to group and sum on dictionary object

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq

We need to store data of the below logical form into a class:

```
"description 1", "activity A", "service A", Month 1 cost, month 2 cost, month 3 cost etc....
```

So I have a class object such as below:

```
Public Class EntityTableRow
    Public Description As String
    Public Activity As String
    Public M1 as Double
    Public M2 as Double
    .....
End Class
```

The M... property would hold monthly costs depending on how many months come in the source data(excel data source). Logically the above class would hold data similar to above mentioned logical form

Now I need to group the rows based on same columns, and get the month costs summed up.

For this, i am trying to use the below Linq query:

```
Dim a As New List(Of EntityTableRow) 
        a = myTable1.TableRows 
        Dim lFinal2 = From el In a Group el By Key = New With {Key el.Description, Key el.Activity} Into Group _ 
                      Select New With {.Activity = Key.Description, _ 
                                       .Country = Key.Activity, _ 
                                       .M1 = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.M1), _ 
                                       .M2 = Group.Sum(Function(x) x.M2)}
```

This seems to be working fine, now how can I change the above Linq query, for the below modified class, where i need to store month costs in dictionary and still get grouped rows, with summation on different month columns?

```
Public Class EntityTableRow
        Public Description As String
        Public Activity As String
        Public MonthCosts As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
    End Class
```

Comment: If your cost values are financial using `Double` is probably a bad idea. `Decimal` is better suited.

Comment: Does the list of Keys within `MonthCosts` Dictionary differ between items from the same group?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim lFinal2 = From el In a
              Group el By Key = New With {Key el.Description, Key el.Activity} Into Group
              Select New With {
                  .Activity = Key.Description,
                  .Country = Key.Activity,
                  .MonthCost =
                      (From k In Group.SelectMany(Function(g) g.MonthCosts.Keys).Distinct()
                       Select New With {
                            .Month = k,
                            .Sum = Group.Sum(Function(g) If(g.MonthCosts.ContainsKey(k), g.MonthCosts(k), 0))
                       }).ToDictionary(Function(i) i.Month, Function(i) i.Sum)
              }
```

Simple test data:

```
Dim a As New List(Of EntityTableRow) From {
    New EntityTableRow With {.Activity = "A", .Description = "D", .MonthCosts = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double) From {{1, 20}, {2, 20}, {3, 20}}},
    New EntityTableRow With {.Activity = "A", .Description = "D", .MonthCosts = New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double) From {{2, 20}, {3, 20}, {4, 20}}}
}
```

And result:
[image]

Comment: The use of `IDctionary` or any other keyed or indexed collection does allow for the sparse population of data. Whilst not initially specified in the question, this could be useful. +1 for the Linq.

Answer (score -3):

It sounds to me like your initial data type should take the form

```
Public Class EntityTableRow
    Public Description As String
    Public Activity As String
    Public MonthCosts As IEnumerable(Of Decimal)
End Class
```

---

I'll show you how to select from an `IEnumerable(Of Decimal)` and group on the order. This should illustrate that an IEnumerable can represent ordered data, dependent on the implementor. First, I'll expand the `EntityTableRow` class definition. There are significant [benefits when using immutable classes](http://msmvps.com/blogs/joacim/archive/2009/09/06/the-untouchables-creating-immutable-objects-with-vb.aspx), and you should agree that directly exposing your member varaibles without properties is considered bad practice.

```
Public Class EntityTableRow

    Private ReadOnly _descritption As String
    Private ReadOnly _activity As String
    Private ReadOnly _monthCosts As IList(Of Decimal)

    Public Sub New( _
            ByVal description As String,
            ByVal activity As String, _
            ByVal monthCosts As IEnumerable(Of Decimal))
        Me._description = description
        Me._activity = activity
        Me._monthCosts = New List(Of Decimal)(monthCosts)
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Description() As String
        Get
            Return Me._description
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property Activity() As String
        Get
            Return Me._activity
        End Get
    End Property

    Public ReadOnly Property MonthCosts() As IEnumerable(Of Decimal)
        Get
            Return Me._monthCosts
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

You can see that the class only exposes `IEnumerable(Of Decimal)` but this sequence does represent ordered data. Now I'll show how you can use linq to group data from `IEnumerable(Of EntityTableRow)` using this definition.

First I'll create some test data.

```
Dim testData As IEnumerable(Of EntityTableRow) = _
    {
        New EntityTableRow("A", "B", New Decimal() {20, 20, 20}),
        New EntityTableRow("A", "B", New Decimal() {Nothing, 20, 20, 20}),
        New EntityTableRow("C", "D", New Decimal() {10, 20, Nothing, 40}),
        New EntityTableRow("C", "D", New Decimal() {50, 60})
    }
```

At this point, I accapet that `IList` would offer better support for sparse population of the data but, that is not defined in the original question. The examples start monotonically from one.

There are several ways to perform the grouping, I'll break it into three simple steps i hop will be easy to follow. Remember this is all lazy evaluated.

First, flatten the data to month level incorporating the month number into the sequence.

```
 Dim allCosts = testData.SelectMany( _
     Function(r) r.MonthCosts.Select( _
         Function(c, i) New With {r.Descriptionr, r.Activity, .Month = i, .Cost = c}))
```

Note the use of index `Select` extension to infer the month from the order.

Next, group and sum the costs by Activity,Description and Month,

```
Dim groupedCosts = allCosts.GroupBy( _
    Function(r) New With {r.Activity, r.Description, r.Month},
    Function(k, s) New With
        {
            k.Description,
            k.Activity,
            k.Month,
            .TotalCost = s.Sum(Function(r) r.Cost)
        })
```

This actually gives you the information required, if it is still desirable you can regroup the months by Description and Activity,

```
Dim groupedDescriptionActivities = groupedCosts.GroupBy( _
    Function(r) New With {r.Description, r.Activity}, _
    Function(k, s) New With
        {
            k.Description,
            k.Activity,
            .MonthCosts = s.Select(Function(r) New With {r.Month, r.TotalCost})
        })
```

Comment: An IEnumerable is just a collection, you lose the context of which month a particular cost is incurred.

Comment: @Rich the data would be enumerated in order, no? What you lose is the denormalised schema.

Comment: @Jodrell Yes, but every item can start from different month and contain different number of items.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, true, does `M1` signify a start point in a way I have missed?

Comment: @Jodrell Maybe you're right, question is not 100% clear in that point. However, you've not answered the question (it's about LINQ, isn't it?) at all. Maybe it should go as an comment, not an answer?

Comment: @Jodrell You don't know what order. It's all at the decision of the implementing class. Which based on this data type definition, you have no guarantee of. More important, I don't think in LINQ that you can group based on a position in an Enumerable. You need to group on a specific data element.

Comment: @Rich I've taken the time to expand my answer and show exactly what I mean. Please take the time to read it, I illustrate using the order of an `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I've expanded my answer to eloborate on my rather thin initial assertion.